# Puppeteer's page.click() is working on some links but not others

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to attempt automation to sign into a web page local to our network.  Chrome throws the normal, "Your connection is not private" https error.  I can click on 'Advanced' and 'Proceed' to get to the sign-in page, but I'd like to play with Puppeteer to do that.

Below is the HTML

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id="primary-button">Back to safety</button>
      <button id="proceed-button" class="secondary-button small-link hidden"></button>
      <button id="details-button" class="secondary-button small-link">Advanced</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My attempts are to send .click() to 'Advanced', then to send .click() to 'Proceed'.  However neither respond.

I have been able to use Puppeteer to launch Google and use page.click('.gb_d') to select the Gmail link successfully.  So perhaps I'm not selecting the element correctly.

My code is below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, /*args:['--start-fullscreen','--window-size=1920,1040']*/});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://10.26.200.215:17001/HORIZON', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
  await page.waitForSelector('#proceed-button');
  await page.click('#proceed-button');



  //await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot click those buttons with Puppeteer, since they aren't part of an actual website (but Chrome's UI). If your server can only be accessed via `https` but doesn't have a valid certificate, that's what you need to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ignoreHTTPSErrors` option set to true:

```
puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, headless: false })
```